# Providing a Contact Name on phone links

Tags: html, ios

I know you can create phone number links using:

```
<a href="tel:1800123456">1 800 123456</a>
```

And on the iPhone for instance, you can tap and hold to get a menu that lets you add the phone to you contacts. Is there a way to provide a default name for the contact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible (yet), as Apple doesn't seem interested in adding [microformats](http://microformats.org) support for iPhone in the near future.